# Dell 1130 printer drivers

Tags: drivers, kernel, printing

Does anyone know how I can get my 14.04 LTS box to drive an older Dell 1130 Laser Printer?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it works on Ubuntu 14.04 but there is a package named `printer-driver-splix` which seems to contain a driver for your printer

```
apt-get install printer-driver-splix
```

The Dell 1130 use a Samsung driver certainly have to select ML-2525 when you will install your printer.

Comment: printer-driver-splix is already the newest version.  not sure how to install printer.

Comment: How did you do?